# HTML changing from Windows to Mac

Tags: css, html, operating-system, dimensions

So i have written a portfolio website, however i am having some trouble. I wrote the site on a windows 7 machine however, at home i use a mac. The windows machine is a 15" screen and the mac a 13" with different resolutions admittedly. Basically, the issue is a sidebar div i have, which shifts down when being viewed on the mac and is where i want it to be when viewing on the windows machine. I have included some screen shots so you get the idea. The first is on Windows 7 and the second on Mac OSX.

[Viewed on Windows](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8261/8753126189_f508a47b7c_b.jpg)

farm8.staticflickr.com/7373/8753141625_140ecbb3ce_b.jpg (viewed on mac)

I originally changed a few things. Here is the code, and then i will explain what i have already tried:

```
<div id="hello" class="container clearfix scroll-content">

<h1>Hello!</h1>

<h2>Allow me to Introduce myself:</h2>
<h2>My Name is <span class="cas">Dom Greenslade</span></h2>
<h3><span class="experience">5</span>Years of Web Development Expereince</h3>
<h3><span class="me">Bachelors Degree</span> in <span class="me">Computer Science</span> Specialising In Programming and Scripting</h3> <br>
<h3>Born, Bred and Reside in: Poole, Dorset</h3><br>
<h3>Currently employed by: Foray Motor Group as Web and Ecommerce Developer</h3>   <br>


<div class="process">
How it's done

<img src="images/process2.png" height="460px">
</div>

</div>
```

and the css:

```
.process{
position: relative;
bottom: 460px;
left:900px;
width: 150px;
height: 500px;
}
```

to see the full code, let me know and i can copy the complete website in here, or you can view the development site at www.domgreenslade.webuda.com

So heres what i have tried:
Changed the position to absolute
Floated to the right and deleted the position.
Changed some of the values to percentages instead of px.

Heres where it gets interesting. 
I was clutching at straws to see what was going on and within the inspect element from within chrome (the browser i designed the site in) and even the sizes of the headings are different from the two operating systems. They are different resolutions, but even when i change the resolution on the Macbook, the sidebar (process) stays where it is. 
The first is on Windows, Second on Mac. Notice the difference in sizes of h1? 46px and 43px depending on the OS? How can i combat this? Its really messing the site up!

[Windows view](http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5331/8754250882_3606212ef1_b.jpg)

(http:/farm4.staticflickr.com/3707/8754266312_7921962613_b.jpg Viewed on Mac

Really and honestly stuck now, what am i missing or what have i done wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use a CSS reset file to balance out the inconsistency in cross browsers.

One widely used CSS reset file is the Meyer's CSS reset.
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Do take note that applying the CSS reset file to your code now would probably mess up some other stuff (such as bold won't be bold by default).

Answer (score 0):

The web has standards for the most part however every browser interrupts these standards differently as well as peoples personal settings on the computer ex. Screen resolution and font settings.

What I would do to correct the layout width to try and suite all browsers and help with other peoples screen resolutions would be to set a Liquid-max-min layout.

```
body{
   width:95%; max-width:1200px; min-width:960px; <!-- These numbers you would have to adjust -->
}
```

For the h1 being different sizes across browsers I would adjust as well by using percentages or small, medium, large, x- large and stay alway from setting font-size to px.

```
h1{
 font-size:300%; <!-- 100% is normal size font so we are multiplying by 3 to be 3x larger-->
}
```

Keep tweaking them and you will have something that you like.

When you test these I would try them in all your browsers to ensure you get a look and feel that allows you to sleep well at night. :)